# Importing dbutils package in python module on databricks

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, dbutils

executing a notebook in Databricks Azure env, that imports the function

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils

def myfunc(..., spark: Sparksession):

    dbutils = DBUtils(spark)

    for file in dbutils.fs.ls(folder):
    ...
```

from a python file results in the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.dbutils
```

How to solve issues like this?

Thanks!

Comment: which databricks are you using azure,aws or community?

Comment: Sorry, I did not specify. It is Azure.

Comment: check if there is a file called `dbutils.py` in your databricks environment.
`%sh ls /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/dbutils.py`

Comment: Yes, the file is there.

Comment: @DorLugasi-Gal: Unfortunately I did not find the solution in my case yet.

Answer (score 0):

On Databricks Repos, when you're working in your notebook, you automatically have access to `spark` and `dbutils`, but you won't have access to that in your modules.

You need to pass `dbutils` explicitly into your Python modules unless you abstract the process of obtaining `dbutils` into a dedicated function.

I came across this on another answer on Stack Overflow

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils

def get_dbutils():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    
    if spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.service.client.enabled") == "true":
        return DBUtils(spark)
    
    try:
        import IPython
        return IPython.get_ipython().user_ns["dbutils"]
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError("IPython is not available. Make sure you're not in a non-IPython environment.")
```

with that, you can modify your code to work like this:

```
def myfunc(...):
    dbutils = get_dbutils()
    for file in dbutils.fs.ls(folder):
```